# Oracle apex how to know which item raises "Leave site" popup

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Mostly I'm setting the feature "Warn on Unsaved Changes" to "Page default". But in some cases, I get the alert popup "Leave site?" even though I did not change anything. probably because of a dynamic action that makes changes in initialization.
I might have many items in a page and I wanted to know if there is a fast way to know which item is raising this alert.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In apex you have access to the entire application metadata through the apex dictionary views. To see the setting for "Warn on unsaved changes" for all items in a page, you can run the following query:

```
SELECT
  application_id,
  page_id,
  item_name,
  warn_on_unsaved_changes
  FROM
  apex_application_page_items
  WHERE application_id = <your_application_id> and page_id = <your_page_id>
```

Similarly, you can see the settings for each page with this query:

```
SELECT
  application_id,
  page_id,
  warn_on_unsaved_changes
  FROM
  apex_application_pages
  WHERE application_id = <your_application_id>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps, but it is showing all the items, and not the specific item that is raising the "leave?" message (even though I didn't change manually any item on the page), which is the one that hard to find.

Comment: I just posted this as an example. Check what the value is for one of the items/pages that has this value for warn_on_unsaved_changes and then change your where clause to only include those items/pages